# Dynamoose query performance degradation, speed delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I'm querying DynamoDB using Dynamoose, but even though there are only about 270 entries, the query speed is significantly slow. What could be the factors causing this performance degradation when the query and model schema are as follows? I would like to inquire how to improve the query speed.

```
const beforeBatchsQuery = new Date();
console.log("query before time", beforeBatchsQuery);

let batchs = await BatchsModel.query("statusValue")
.eq(statusValue)
.using("statusValue-sortKey-index")
.where("sortKey")
.ge(sortKey)
.all()
.exec();

const afterBatchsQuery = new Date();
console.log("query after time", afterBatchsQuery);
```

```
const schema = new dynamoose.Schema(
  {
    pk: {
      type: String,
      // validate: (val) => /^batch#/.test(val),
      hashKey: true,
    },
    sk: {
      type: String,
      rangeKey: true,
    },
    afterTuition: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    applicationProcess: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [
        {
          type: Array,
          schema: [String],
          required: false,
        },
      ],
      required: false,
    },
    applicationProcessText: String,

    batchId: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    batchName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    bootOption: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    brandName: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    campId: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    campUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    challengeWay: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    city: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    classTypeOption: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    company: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    companyId: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    companyIds: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [
        {
          type: Object,
          schema: {
            companyId: String,
            companyRole: String,
            companyName: String,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    computer: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    computerOption: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    costOption: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    courseValue: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    createDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    curriculumFile: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },

    curriculumUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    cyclic: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    dateFixed: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        regDate: String,
        regEndDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        startDate: String,
      },
    },
    dateStrings: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        regDate: String,
        regEndDate: String,
        endDate: String,
        startDate: String,
      },
    },
    deleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    description: {
      type: [Object, String],
      schema: {
        benefits: {
          type: Array,
          schema: [String],
          required: false,
        },
        targets: {
          type: Array,
          schema: [String],
          required: false,
        },
        goals: {
          type: Array,
          schema: [String],
          required: false,
        },
      },
      schema: String,
      required: false,
    },

    earlyBirdEndDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    endDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    endDateFixed: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    entryFee: {
      type: [Number, dynamoose.type.NULL],
      required: false,
    },
    etcComputerChecked: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    etcSubsidyChecked: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    etcSubsidyText: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    govtCost: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    govtCostValue: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    hasTracks: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    hrdSeperated: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    jobOpportunityText: String,

    jobSearchingServiceValues: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [Number],
    },
    keywords: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
    },

    nbcardBalance: Boolean,
    nbcardRequired: Boolean,
    offlineRequired: Boolean,
    onoff: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    openCycle: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },

    partTime: Boolean,
    passRequired: Boolean,
    period: Number,
    place: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    preCourseOption: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
    },
    preferentialTreatment: String,
    preNotice: Boolean,
    preNoticeEndDate: String,
    prepLevel: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
    },
    projectValues: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [Number],
    },
    qualification: String,
    quota: Number,
    recommendedPreKnowledge: String,
    redirectCamp: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        batchId: String,
        title: String,
        campId: String,
      },
      required: false,
    },
    regDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    regDateFixed: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    regEndDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    regEndDateFixed: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    remark: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    requiredPreKnowledge: String,
    returnFee: {
      type: [Number, dynamoose.type.NULL],
      required: false,
    },
    reviews: {
      type: [String, dynamoose.type.NULL],
      required: false,
    },
    searchKeywords: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        keyword: String,
        dateRestrict: Number,
        includeKeyword: String,
      },
    },    
    sortKey: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    startDate: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    startDateFixed: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    statusValue: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      index: {
        global: true,
        name: "statusValue-sortKey-index",
        hashKey: "statusValue",
        rangeKey: "sortKey",
        project: true,
        throughput: "ON_DEMAND",
      },
    },
    studyDayOption: Number,
    studyTime: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [
        {
          type: Object,
          schema: {
            startTime: String,
            endTime: String,
          },
        },
      ],
      required: false,
    },
    studyTimeFixed: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [Boolean],
    },
    studyTimePerUnit: {
      type: [String, Number],
      required: false,
    },
    studyTimeUnit: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    subsidyValues: Array,
    tags: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [String],
      required: false,
    },
    timeSpecified: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        regEndDate: Boolean,
        regDate: Boolean,
      },
      required: false,
    },
    timeStrings: {
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        regEndDate: String,
        regDate: String,
      },
      required: false,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    tracks: {
      type: Array,
      schema: [
        {
          type: Object,
          schema: {
            category: String,
            keywords: {
              type: Array,
              schema: [String],
              required: false,
            },
            quota: Number,
            tags: {
              type: Array,
              schema: [String],
              required: false,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      required: false,
    },
    tuition: Number,

    updatedAt: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    saveUnknown: ["studyTimes.**", "assets.**", "jobOpportunityValues.**", "hrd.**", "earlyBird.**" ],
    indexes: {
      "statusValue-sortKey-index": { 
          type: 'global',
          hashKey: 'statusValue',
          rangeKey: 'sortKey',
          project: true, // 모든 필드 포함 (또는 필요한 필드만 지정)
          // throughput: "ON_DEMAND"
      }
    }
  }
);

const BatchsModel = dynamoose.model("abcd", schema, {
  create: false,
  waitForActive: false
});

module.exports = BatchsModel;
```

It takes about 8-10 seconds to execute the query. Could you please suggest ways to improve the query speed?

Currently, the query speed is taking about 8-10 seconds, but I would like to see a significant improvement in this speed. Ideally, it would be great if it could be reduced to within 1 second.

Comment: What does your DynamoDB Cloudwatch latency say?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the query? DynamoDB is designed for LOOKUP queries where you have the key of the object(s) you want to get. You need to design the schema (including the secondary indexes) to ensure you don't need to scan too much data to retrieve the records.